# RDLC - Error when I set PageName

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting, rdlc

I have a report viewer with group (pagebrake "Between") tablix, but when i set the PageName to rename Excel sheet I got this error:

> An exception of type
>   'Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalProcessingException' occurred in
>   Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: An error occurred during local report
>   processing.

InnerException

> The report definition is not valid.  Details: The report definition
>   has an invalid target namespace
>   'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/reportdefinition'
>   which cannot be upgraded.

Is there a bug?

Thanks.

Comment: what version of VS are you using? can you confirm that the error appears even if you save the report without modifying it?

Comment: My version of VS is 2015.  The error appears if I set the PageName, but if I delete it it still gives error.

Comment: RDLC is super sensitive to versions. 2008, 2010 and 2015 reports and servers don't mix nicely.  The reports can be upgraded, but not always automatically.

Comment: On version 2013 appears this: `The report definition is not valid.  Details: The report definition has an invalid target namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/reportdefinition' which cannot be upgraded.`

Comment: I got guys: [just install it](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ReportViewer.2015.Runtime/) Thank you so much